# Extjs Conditional date renderer

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I have a grid in my application which shows date in a field. Now I want to show the field in bold format if the day is in last week. But on two rows shows my desired output. I am not understanding where is the fault of my condition. Can anybody help me on this please ? here is my code below :

```
{
            text: 'Start',  
            dataIndex: 'weekstart',
            flex: 1,
            renderer: function(value, metaData){
                var day = new Date(value) - 0,
                lastDay = Ext.Date.getLastDateOfMonth(value)-0,
                lastWeek = lastDay - 7;
                console.log('day >>> '+day,'lastDay >>> '+ lastDay, 'lastWeek >>> '+lastWeek);
                    return day >= lastWeek ? '<b>' + Ext.Date.format(value, 'M d, Y') + '</b>' : Ext.Date.format(value, 'M d, Y') ;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `day` and `lastDay` are timestamps, to have this you should use timestamp in `lastWeek`: `lastWeek = lastDay - 7*24*3600*1000`.

Anyway IMO it's better to use `getRowClass` to format values.
In grid config try to specify `viewConfig`:

```
viewConfig: {
    getRowClass: function(record, rowIndex, rowParams, store){
        var value = record.get('lastChange'),
            day = value.getDate(),
            lastDay = Ext.Date.getDaysInMonth(value),
            lastWeek = lastDay - 6;
        return day >= lastWeek ? 'last-week' : '';
    }
}
```

In column definition specify class additional class: `tdCls: 'date-column'` and then you can format column in css:

```
.last-week .date-column {
    font-weight: bold;
}​
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/36n4m/1/

Comment: This is a better solution than the @Sumon Bappi's one. +1

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have completed it just like below :

```
 {
                text: 'Start',  
                dataIndex: 'weekstart',
                width: 84,
                renderer: function(value, metaData, record, row, col, store, gridView){
                    var day = value.getDate(),
                    lastDay = Ext.Date.getDaysInMonth(value),
                    lastWeek = lastDay - 6;
//                    console.log( 'row >>> '+ row,'   day >>> '+ day,'   lastDay >>> '+ lastDay, '   lastWeek >>> '+ lastWeek );
                        return day >= lastWeek ? '<b>' + Ext.Date.format(value, 'M d, Y') + '</b>' : Ext.Date.format(value, 'M d, Y') ;
                }
            }
```